# Json and Internal db

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, json

I need to save the information that I get from a json, the result did a webserver with php MySql connection, and save me the information in an internal db, so I do not have to download every time the json, what can I use to save information from the json directly to the database?

Comment: Parse the JSON and store the same inside the database. Simple enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own SQLite data base in the android device and the table should like the web data base.If your web data base is updated then your android device need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the data in your app's SQLite database:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db